# Dynamically setting variables in outer scope from WF 4 activity

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

How can I dynamically set the values of variables from the parent scope in a Windows Workflow Foundation activity under .NET 4?

An attempt that failed (drop on a Sequence activity on a workflow where the Sequence has an int variable named Test):

```
public sealed class CodeActivity1 : NativeActivity
{
    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        _locationReferences =
            metadata.Environment.GetLocationReferences().ToList();

        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        LocationReference locationReference =
            _locationReferences.Find(
                x => x.Name == "Test" && x.Type == typeof (int));

        if (locationReference != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                locationReference.Name + " " + locationReference.Type);

            // Blows up here.
            Location location = locationReference.GetLocation(context);
            location.Value = 5;
        }
    }

    private List<LocationReference> _locationReferences;
}
```

This results in:

> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message=Activity '1.2: CodeActivity1'
>   cannot access this variable because it
>   is declared at the scope of activity
>   '1.1: Sequence'.  An activity can only
>   access its own implementation
>   variables.

It does find the variable; it just can't get or set its value.

The variable name ("Test" in the above example) would not be known until runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal way of handling this is to define an OutArgument and in the workflow designer bind the OutArgument to your variable. In the activity you only work with the argument. Using a NativeActivity gives you an OutArgument named Result but just adding a property of OUtArgument will do just fine.

Another benefit is you don't need to know "magic" variable names to store results in.

**Update because the code in the comment below is unreadable.**

Try adding the following just before the line it blows up:

```
var pi = context.GetType().GetProperty("AllowChainedEnvironmentAccess", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); 
pi.SetValue(context, true, null);
```

Totally not supported so use with care :-)

Comment: I have a requirement that the clients do not have hardcoded knowledge of the workflow. We're used to BPMs where you can create a process by passing in name,value pairs to initialize the fields, interrogate a running process to get a list of fields and then set them, etc. It's more flexible, discoverable, and decoupled at the cost of runtime safety. Going from a BPM to WF is like moving from a dynamically typed language to a statically typed language. I think we have two options: fake it with a variable of type Dictionary<string, object> or interrogate the WSDL.

Comment: I think I completely misunderstood your question. I was under the impression you where trying to use specific workflow variables and that has nothing to do with WSDL and WCF clients. The WCF request parameters are the result of Receive parameters only. How you tie the result to internal workflow variables, or even ignore the value, is completely transparent to the client application.

Comment: @Maurice - I tried to keep the example simple. I wanted the Receive parameter to be a fixed type, with a collection of name,value pairs. When called it would dynamically update any variables in scope that had matching names.

Comment: Try adding the following just before the line it blows up: 
var pi = context.GetType().GetProperty("AllowChainedEnvironmentAccess", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
pi.SetValue(context, true, new object[0]);
Totally not supported so use with care :-)

Comment: Since that's not an indexed property according to Reflector, it should be pi.SetValue(context, true, null). Either way, it works! I will try to avoid doing this in production. Thanks again! :)

Comment: You are right, the third parameter should have been null, it's been a while with reflection.